# Cannot find the maximum value of a function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Consider the following function:

$a Sin(x)+b Cos(x)$

I tried to obtain the maximum value of this function using [`MaxValue[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaxValue.html):

```
MaxValue[a Sin[x] + b Cos[x], x, Reals]
```

I expect *Mathematica* to return the following answer:

$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

But *Mathematica* cannot find the answer. Why does this happen?

Comment: note it cant even do this: `MaxValue[a Sin[x], x, Reals]`

Comment: @george2079 But I am puzzled, is it a bug or a feature ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is essentially what b.g did, except by using Max instead of the second derivative constraint we get the result without rewriting the original expression.

```
f[x_] = a Sin[x] + b Cos[x];
Simplify[
    Max[f[x] /. Solve[ {f'[x] == 0 }, x] ],
       Assumptions -> {Element[a, Reals], Element[b, Reals], 
         Element[C[1], Integers]}]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]
> ```

I'm a bit puzzled why the conditional expression on `C[1]` doesn't simplify out
on its own when the `C[1]` is gone from the expression..?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
MaxValue[a Sin[x] + b Cos[x] /. x -> 2 ArcTan[t] // TrigExpand, t, Reals]

MaxValue[{y, Reduce[{y == a Sin[x] + b Cos[x], #}, y, {x}, Reals]}, y]& /@
  {Xor[a == 0, b == 0], a!=0 && b!=0} // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Comment: not quite.. if a==0 the max is abs[b].  I suppose because ArcTan doesn't admit the full range of angles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The ranges of `x` and `ArcTan[t]` are different. How come `x` can be substituted with `ArcTan[t]`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a more down to earth method :

```
func = Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] Sin[x + f];
sol = First@Solve[{D[func, {x, 1}] == 0, D[func, {x, 2}] < 0, 
 f \[Element] Reals, a \[Element] Reals, b \[Element] Reals}, x, Reals];

Simplify[func /. sol, Assumptions -> C[1] \[Element] Integers]
(* Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] *)
```

Comment: Would you please explain why `a Sin[x] + b Cos[x]` is defined as `Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] Sin[x + f]`.

Comment: You can do `TrigExpand[ Sin[x + f]]` and match `Cos[f]` to `a/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]` and `Sin[f]` to `b/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]`.